# Unable to connect to j2me device emulator

Tags: java-me

I am having trouble in testing a Midlet. I am using j2me sdk 3, the Midlet builds successfully, but when i try to run it, it fails and it shows the following message in the log:

> > Failed to connect to device {0}!
> >     Reason:
> >     Emulator {0} terminated while waiting for it to register!

Comment: does anyone know the solution for this.. i already try solutions provided but still no luck... i'm always disconnecting my computer to internet for me to run the emulator.

Comment: @Rob Try installing older version (Sun SDK 3.0), I got one from last year, never got around to delete it, and this version works with DEP exception, while the built in 3.0.5 in Netbeans don't work even after I tried any workaround listed here

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. On the next system restart there where message about runMidlet crash due to DEP (Data Execution Prevention).

After turning off DEP all started to work perfect.

In case it could help, it was on Win2003, Java ME SDK 3.0.

UPDATE: 
I advise to turn off DEP for all programs (it is "Turn on DEP for essential Windows programs and services only" option). 
In my case turning off DEP for single runMidlet.exe had only temporary effect.

See also [Java ME SDK Team blog entry on this](http://blogs.oracle.com/javamesdk/entry/first_aid_when_emulator_doesn#comment-1273341759000)

Comment: Same thing on Win7 x86. The bad thing is that runMidlet was failing silently. Just add `runMidlet.exe` located in `NetBeans/mobility/Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0/runtimes/cldc-hi-javafx/bin` to the list of DEP-disabled programs in `System->Sytem Properties->Advanced->Performace->Data Execution Protection->Turn on DEP for all programs and services except those I select` and you're ready to go! :-)

Comment: This trick helped me last year. Not so in current Netbeans (7.1.1) with built in Oracle ME SDK 3.05. I then installed the old emulator (Sun ME SDK 3.0) and it runs like a charm. Not sure if it's because the different binary, different config, different location or maybe my laptop (it won't start when the processor DEP support on the BIOS are disabled)

Comment: @Martheen, may `bcdedit.exe /set {current} nx AlwaysOff` will help you? Read more [here](http://windows7themes.net/disable-windows-data-execution-prevention-in-windows-7-vista.html)

Comment: @SergiyKheylyk Thanks :) For now I'm just gonna keep DEP on for all except the old emulator (paranoid and all), but I'll try your trick on my other PC

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to increase the debugger timeout value. I work in WTK 2.5.x so I'm not sure where this setting is exposed (are you on Netbeans?) in version 3.0.

Somewhat out-of-date instructions for [Eclipse](http://www.forum.nokia.com/infocenter/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-F7F6BFF7-4812-4F0A-825B-529A1BFC688F.html) and [Netbeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqJ2MEIncreaseDebuggerTimeout).

Answer (score 0):

Just go to tools/java platform, select the CLDC Framework blah blah blah and Click refresh.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Please could you provide some more details, and perhaps tidy it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If  you are using Linux as your operating system just you need to type the command 'setenforce permissive' in the terminal.It will solve the issue.
Rishabh

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the DEP issue mentioned in other answers, there is a useful list of solutions to common problems [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamesdk/entry/first_aid_when_emulator_doesn).