# J2ME emulator not showing: Emulator 0 terminated while waiting for it to register

Tags: java, java-me, midp, cldc, java-wireless-toolkit

I tried a simple HelloWorld program (CLDC and MIDP) in Java Wireless toolkit but when I tried in Java ME SDK it builds fine but the emulator is not coming. It shows the following message

```
Starting emulator in execution mode
Error
Failed to connect to device 0!
Reason:
Emulator 0 terminated while waiting for it to register!
```

I am on Windows XP and using Java ME Platform SDK 3.0 and I am not using Netbeans or Eclipse.

Comment: your firewall might blocking it.

Comment: yes a firewall box came but i selected "Unblock" but then also i getting the same error. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: open firewall from control panel and add emulator in its option.

Comment: When i opened firewall under the Exception tag i selected "Add program" then a list came in that list i had the option of selecting "java ME platform sdk 3.0" but no "emulator" so should i add the "Java ME sdk 3.0" ?

Comment: In my Xp System when SDK runs for first time, my firewal asks me wheather to allow or reject Emulator, so i select "allow" , that's all I know.

Comment: I tried add "JAva ME paltform SDK 3.0" but i get the same error

Comment: Well I guess, someone else might face same problem , so he can guide you better

Comment: by the way are you using any anti-virus ? if yes , then check its firewall permission too.

Comment: I tried the Demo projects which come with ME SDk 3.0, when i run these demo projects a firewall message comes and i select "Unblock" and the application runs. But when i make my own projects and execute them i don't even get the firewall message and what i get is the above error in my question

Comment: Then please upload your code , and also tell me the version of CLDC & MIDP

Comment: There is no need to upload the code because when i create a new MIDlet project, the ME SDK 3.0 automatically creates a HEllo MIDlet for us which we can execute but i am not able to execute since i am having the above problem....At the time of creating the MIDlet there are default selection i accept i.e. CLDC 1.1 and MIDlet 2.0

Comment: check answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233226/unable-to-connect-to-j2me-device-emulator

Comment: Now my MIDlet is running just because i selected a different emulator. In ME SDK there are about 7 to 8 CLDC devices so why does my MIDlet works in only some CLDC emulator and why not in others? The devices in which my mIDlet doesn't work has the same error as my questions. Anyways thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Turn it off completely will solve the problem! What a full-of-error emulator!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem, and none of the firewall/IDE refresh/DEP solutions worked. It turns out the Java ME SDK needs a newer version of JAXB (2.2) than the one that comes with JDK 6 (2.1).

To fix this, create a "%JAVA_HOME%\lib\endorsed" directory (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_03\jre\lib\endorsed for me), download a new jaxb-api.jar (http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/jaxb-api/jaxb-api-2.2.3.jar.zip worked for me), and unzip it into lib\endorsed.